# A deleted user's display name is not user12345

Tags: discussion, support, deleted-users

Deleted users' display names are like `user12345` but the one who asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/751124) is named "somebody." Was that their real display name? If so, why do some deleted users get to keep their names and others do not?

Comment: Somebody wanted to ask a question. Anybody could have asked it, but they were afraid of downvotes. In the end, Nobody asked it, even though it would have been helpful to Everybody.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`somebody` was their real display name at the time their account was deleted. You see a display name on the question because posts were not anonymised back when that account was deleted. I suspect that the name 'somebody' was [picked deliberately to manually anonymise](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26844/there-needs-to-be-a-way-to-delete-content-or-disassociate-your-account-from-said/26853#26853).

That procedure is now long since obsolete. These days, when an account is deleted, posts are anonymised automatically. There is no option to put a different name on posts.

Note that anonymising posts doesn't stretch to comment contents; if someone used `@displayname` to ping the post author in comments, then the name in such comments is not affected.